# JavaScript function not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Below function is working fine for IE, but not working for Mozilla and other browsers:

```
function CloseSession() {        
 alert("Inside Close");  
  if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY<0)) {  
    alert("Inside Events");  
    location.href = '/forms/sessionkill.aspx';  
  }    
}
```

What I am trying to do is, I have a button on a page after clicking on that button, a page in opened in new window having session, the session will be maintained until user closes the browser. on the new page there is right navigation which have different links for different pages. If I directly call my sessionkill.aspx it kills the session whenever a link is clicked on window unload function.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, it's a reasonable (if newbie) question

Comment: The OP has been a member of the site for 7 months! And has not learned to format code yet, forcing other responsible community members to do it for him. I think the downvote was well deserved.

Comment: Dear I know its really bad but I tried to format above code, can you please give some tips for this

Comment: @Cerebrus - ahhhh. Alles klar!

Comment: @Manoj - there's a toolbar right there, try it out!

Comment: What's with the lack of community spirit here?  Downvote or whatever, but there's no need to rag on the guy.  If you have time to complain, you have time to edit the post or offer a suggestion.  Sheesh!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla does not set the global `window.event` property.

I'd recommend using an AJAX framework, such as JQuery (or even Microsoft AJAX).

```
function CloseSession(event) {   
  // use Mozilla event parameter, or window.event if that was not passed     
  event = event || window.event; 
  alert("Inside Close");  
  if ((event.clientX < 0) || (event.clientY<0)) {  
    alert("Inside Events");  
    location.href = '/forms/sessionkill.aspx';  
  }    
}
```

Update: if you were using JQuery:

```
function CloseSession(e) {   
  alert("Inside Close");  
  if ((e.pageX < 0) || (e.pageX < 0)) {  
    alert("Inside Events");  
    location.href = '/forms/sessionkill.aspx';  
  }    
}
```

Comment: How can I use this function on window.onbeforeunload

Comment: The jquery example would be similar, except that event would be passed as a parameter (so no need for the check) and event.pageX and event.pageY instead of clientX and clientY. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event

Comment: above code is not working for mozilla its calling the function and first alert is called but alert("Inside Events") is not called. However working fine for IE

Comment: Can I have jquery solution for above problem

Comment: Why is it not working - well how about clientX and clientY is never less than 0. Try outputting these values before the if statement.